# np.where dataframe column .isin dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
TEL1 TEL2 TEL3    NAME
0   10  12  11  Ben
1   18  18  14  Ben
2   19  12  15  Ben
3   10  17  21  Ben
4   19  19  23  Ben
5   12  18  15  Ben
6   15  13  19  Ben
```

The aim of my python code is to remove numbers that exist anywhere in TEL1 vs. TEL2, TEL2 vs. TEL3, TEL3 vs. TEL1. Between all three columns there should be unique numbers.

I am using to dedupe between TEL1 and TEL2, TEL2 and TEL3 and it's working.:

```
df['TEL1'] = np.where(df['TEL1'].isin(df['TEL2']), '', df['TEL1'])
df['TEL2'] = np.where(df['TEL2'].isin(df['TEL3']), '', df['TEL2'])
```

Result:

```
TEL1 TEL2 TEL3 NAME
0   10  12  11  Ben
1       18  14  Ben
2       12  15  Ben
3   10  17  21  Ben
4           23  Ben
5       18  15  Ben
6   15  13  19  Ben
```

However, when I add the following code it doesn't work and shows the same output as above:

```
df['TEL3'] = np.where(df['TEL3'].isin(df['TEL1']), '', df['TEL3'])
```

Expected result would be this (the 15 in the TEL3 column removed):

```
TEL1 TEL2 TEL3 NAME
0   10  12  11  Ben
1       18  14  Ben
2       12      Ben
3   10  17  21  Ben
4           23  Ben
5       18  15  Ben
6   15  13  19  Ben
```

This may not be the most efficient way of trying to achieve what I am after but I understand what the code is trying to do. If there's a more efficient way that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why is the 15 removed?

Comment: the 15 is removed from TEL3 because it exists in TEL1

Comment: even though it’s not in the same row?

Comment: That's correct, what I am trying to use the code for is to create unique telephone numbers between all telephone fields (TEL1-TEL3) regardless of where they appear in the column.

Comment: The goal is to remove duplicates between TEL1-TEL3 in the whole dataframe. I will focus on removing duplicate rows later.

Comment: For some context, each row represents a contact name and three telephone numbers. We do not want to dial the same number twice, across contacts.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the outcome I was after. I want to drop duplicates and then de-dupe rows based on TEL1-TEL3 afterwards. It will leave me with rows of contact names in the TEL1-TEL3 format I am after.

Comment: Then perhaps you're after `df.set_index('NAME', append=True).stack().drop_duplicates().unstack(2)` Each number will be unique and it drops duplicates across the entire set of fields, and then reshapes back to the original

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC this should solve your whole problem. A number can only appear once across the whole frame.

```
df.set_index('NAME', append=True).stack().drop_duplicates().unstack(2).reset_index(level=1)
```

#### Output:

```
  NAME  TEL1  TEL2  TEL3
0  Ben  10.0  12.0  11.0
1  Ben  18.0   NaN  14.0
2  Ben  19.0   NaN  15.0
3  Ben   NaN  17.0  21.0
4  Ben   NaN   NaN  23.0
6  Ben   NaN  13.0   NaN
```